# PSQL file execution

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, enterprisedb

I am trying to execute a .sql file using UNIX command line for postgres 9.5. I have tried

```
psql -s localhost -d postgres < filename.sql
```

where `postgres` is the name of my database, as well as

```
psql postgres username < filename.sql
```

and also

```
psql -af filename.sql
```

and I get the result:

```
Usage: /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/scripts/runpsql.sh [wait]
```

for each of these runs. The scripts did not seem to execute, but got no error messages. I am running on Mac OSX.

Comment: What is the result of `type psql`?

Comment: `psql is aliased to '/Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/scripts/runpsql.sh'`

Comment: I can guess that you have some product of EnterpriseDB instead of the "pure" PostgreSQL installed. If so then add the `enterprisedb` tag to the your question to get more relevant answers (sorry, have no any experience with EDB).

Comment: thanks. i did download through```http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#macosx```, hopefully this gives more information to my problem if there is a problem with downloading this way.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like the issue is with the command you are trying to run, specifically with the -s option. According to the PostgreSQL documentation, the -s option is used to specify the name of the system database to connect to, not the hostname.

Instead, try the following command to execute your SQL file:

```
psql -d postgres -U username -f filename.sql
```

Comment: Could you provide a link to where in the PostgreSQL documentation you found this information? This reads a lot like a ChatGPT response.